# Mercurial - export with history file inside archive

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I want to make a delivery of my project by using "hg archive". The only problem I see is that there is no history file in that archive. Is there a way to export full history into the same file?

By history I mean revision description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After running `hg archive` you could run `hg log --style compact > history.log`. You would end up with a file containing things like:

```
598[tip][master]   9e6089ab583e   2012-01-31 17:33 -0800   ludovic
  Fixed bug with invalid cache deleting the server cache.

597   31db8a573628   2012-01-31 17:33 -0800   ludovic
  Added ability to bake a single directory.

596   94984a322204   2012-01-31 17:32 -0800   ludovic
  Added helper function to create dummy posts.

595[github/master]   7cc23cfe234b   2012-01-30 11:55 -0800   ludovic
  Added another test for file baking.

594   044b67accf3c   2012-01-30 11:55 -0800   ludovic
  Throw an error about not supporting asset sub-directories.

593   dd1943298b06   2012-01-30 10:23 -0800   ludovic
  Make `PieCrustPlugin::getName` abstract.
```

You can customize the output of `hg log` with any of the predefined styles, or [with a style of your own](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/customizing-the-output-of-mercurial.html), depending on how much information your want in that history file.

Answer (score 2):

`hg archive` is specifically designed to *remove* any historical context/version control data.

If you want the history of a repository, just copy the actual repository.

Comment: By history I mean revision description.

Comment: You'd have to write it in afterwards.

Comment: It contain four lines:
repo: 
node: 
branch: default
tag: